# Add tag synonym to the CNG tag?

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms

I think that "natural-gas" should be a tag synonym for the CNG tag but...

1. You have to have enough people with enough tag rep (who have enough votes in the tag) to vote on the synonym
2. You need to get those people to vote on the synonym to approve

Are there any mods out there that can make this change?

Comment: Can you help @BobCross?

Comment: Unfortuately, I think this question is now moot. When I changed the tag from [tag:natural-gas] to [tag:cng], the natural-gas one went away. All is as it should be.